# How to add a ripple effect to my custom view drawn element?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-canvas, android-view

I am trying to add click ripple effect to my custom view element. It is kind of a progress indicator with several circles. Circles are clickable. So I want to add ripple effect to the circle which user clicks. The ripple effect has to be bounded by circle radius.  I cannot find any tutorial how can I do it.

[image]

Whole widget drawn programmatically. It isn't 
a compound view.

Comment: looks like those circles are small enough that your finger would cover them completely while pressing them, effectively preventing you from seeing the ripple

Comment: I am interested in the opportunity to make such effect.

Comment: @DanMan check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73571189/4288054
How to draw ripple effect on any custom view